# How to replace blogger image URL parameters

Tags: image, url, post, blogger, new-operator

I would like to change all mediathumbnail.url image (first image of the post) in blogger website as follows.

Replace s72-c to s300-c

or

Replace s1600 to s300-c

However i want to change all featured images to s300-c

Please help me to find out a way to do it !

Comment: could you post the code you are trying to edit?

Answer (score 0):

Use this JavaScript function to resize your images

```
function resizeImage(img, size, newsize) {
    return img.replace(size, newsize)
}

resizeImage(media$thumbnail.url, 's72', 's300-c');

// media$thumbnail.url is your media URL getting from the blogger feed
```